# Mysql Statement to pull info from database in particular order with subsets

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called pages which I use for several things, including the navigation of the site. Within that table I have pagenames, parentid, navid(set to 1 if it is in the nav, otherwise 0 and don't count it ), and navorder which dictates the order. I am currently ripping through the table pulling all parents then doing a select statement to pull all children ( if they exist ) for that parent to make the dropdown for the nav. If there are 8 parents and each have children that could end up being a lot of select statements every time the page loads. I was wondering if there is a better way to do this within 1 sql call that would return an array with all the parent children in order.

Im hoping someone with a strong MySQL background could nudge me in the right direction.

Comment: why didn't you create several tables? It seems you have one-to-many relationships. If you have the tables separated, you could create joins and you can forget about having to come up with a group by solution.

Comment: @Erick anytime I build anything with a parent child relationship that goes no more then 3 levels I try to keep it in one table. I just feel its more efficient but am always open to learning a better way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT parent.id, child.id
FROM pages parent LEFT JOIN 
pages child ON parent.id = pages.parentid
WHERE parent.parentid IS NULL
ORDER BY parent.navorder, child.navorder
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM pages 
WHERE parentid = *the page id* AND navid = 1 
ORDER BY *column you want to sort by*
```

Add `ASC` or `DESC` to the end of that for ascending/descending

Which language are you coding in?

see: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: I can pull the parents and then the children after, what I am trying to do is pull everything in one query instead of doing a bunch of selects. I am coding in PHP. I could pull everything then use PHP to manipulate it which is the path im going down now.